# How to make group in Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

I need to group users in the list by department. Like this:

[image]

Clicking on the group name should open the list. Or tell me how you can filter a spinner with a large number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use ExpandableListView you can follow this library

[ExpandableListView](https://github.com/Android-Tutorials-Hub/expandable-list-view-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView)